# Lookup graph api, flow or similar from sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, microsoft-graph

Without any programming background, I'm trying to do something that should be easy to me. I have a Sharepoint list on Sharepoint Online and Azure AD.

Columns: User, email, jobtitle, phone, department, country, custom1, custom2

User is a person field. The rest is text.

Now, I want when I select a user, that a lookup can take care of filling out the rest.

Shouldn't it be easy? User info is everywhere in O365.

I can't figure it out. I doesn't matter to me if i use graph/flow/workflow, external connectors, or whatever it's called, just as long as I don't need third party plugins.

Any ideas and examples?